# Invalid Page in iOS webview for Lightning Community

Tags: community, lightning, napili

We have a Napili template on our community [here](https://crm-science.force.com/s/). When a user clicks on this link from the twitter app on iOS, they get a message: 'Invalid Page' as described [here](https://twitter.com/carlbrundage/status/766801639567192064). When they open in Safari, the community loads as expected. The problem seems to be with iOS webview (is this supported by SF?) or with the Community config somewhere.

Has this problem been reported elsewhere and are there any known fixes/workarounds besides for asking users to open with their browser?

Comment: To add to the issue, we just found out that it's not limited to twitter + iOS, it seems that the Lightning Community has some malformed expectations of the header, I don't quite understand.  Same error in a basic website tester "Invalid Page": http://nibbler.silktide.com/en_US/reports/crm-science.force.com

Comment: As a workaround, we setup a new page and a redirect.

Comment: Page that works: https://crm-science.force.com/s/groups  Fails google page test: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcrm-science.force.com%2Fs%2Fgroups

There is something very strange going on with lightning community builder sites. It's like the header being analyzed by the server is too strict in it's expectations.  Referer, Accept etc.

Comment: This is the only way we can get a page to load in ios twitter app: https://crm-science.force.com/s/groups  so we setup a bunch of redirects, not desirable

Answer (score 1):

Per Jake, a workaround "solution" is to setup another page for the site and do this redirect (we will switch to 301 redirects eventually).

Community Builder > Page Manager > Add New Page > Select Custom Page Template

Community Builder > Page Editor > Select 'New Page' > Drag your lightning components on to Page and save your page.

Then configure these redirects

Setup > Sites > Community > URL Redirects

[image: url redirects]

This solution is NOT ideal, we would like the root site at /s to be the landing page.  But a good workaround nonetheless.  This works in twitter ios browser.

Still having an error trying to use host-tracker.com to monitor the website at this new URL, and google insights page test fails as well, get's the same "Invalid Page" error.